How to use TimePickerDialog only in clock mode?
Is it possible to hide button that switch picker in a digit mode?
I see a that TimePickerDialog has method setView(view) from parent AlertDialog, but what is the view I need to pass to him?
I'am try make smthg like
val picker = TimePickerDialog(context, callBack, currentHour, currentMinute, true)
val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_time_picker_dialog, null)
picker.setView(view)

but what is the my_time_picker_dialog I should create?

